# Image.Height TemplateBinding does not work

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls, dependency-properties

I have created a CustomControl implemented from Button class in WPF.

```
public class ImageButton : Button
{
      ...

       public int ImageHeight
       {
           get { return (int)GetValue(ImageHeightProperty); }
           set { SetValue(ImageHeightProperty, value); }
       }
       public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageHeightProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("ImageHeight", typeof(int), typeof(ImageButton), new UIPropertyMetadata(32)); 

       ...
}
```

And I have resource template like this:

```
<Setter Property="Template">
   <Setter.Value>
     <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type custom:ImageButton}">
       <Border>
         <StackPanel>
          <Image Name="image" Height="{TemplateBinding ImageHeight}"/>
          <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />
         </StackPanel>
       </Border>
     <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
   </ControlTemplate>
 </Setter.Value>
```

ImageHeight dependecy property doesn't binding.
When I write like as below it works successful.

```
Height="32"
```

What is wrong with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=Progress}` instead ?

See these answers for more details...

[WPF TemplateBinding vs RelativeSource TemplatedParent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1131222/wpf-templatebinding-vs-relativesource-templatedparent)

[Binding custom dependency property to custom WPF style](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973372/binding-custom-dependency-property-to-custom-wpf-style)

hope this helps

Comment: It worked. Thanks. In same control I have `<TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Text}" />`. **Text** also is a DependecyPropety and it works without any error. I didn't understand what is difference between these 2 dp.

Comment: well that's that first link - one is compiler-time, another runtime - custom properties seem not be fully recognizable by XAML template. The other one binds later.