# Wpf color animation binding

Tags: wpf, binding, coloranimation

I have stumbled upon a really annoying problem, it would seem to be something trivial to achieve but I cannot figure out a solution. What I want to do is bind the *To* property of a ColorAnimation to a DependencyProperty called MouseOverColor. This is what my style looks like:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource SolidBlueDark}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
  <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}" />
  <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
  <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="MouseOverColor" Value="Cyan" />
  <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1" />
  <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center" />
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:Button}">
        <Grid>
          <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
              <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.4" />
              </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
              <VisualState Name="Normal" />
              <VisualState Name="MouseOver">
                <Storyboard>
                  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="Border" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).Color" To="{TemplateBinding MouseOverColor}" />
                </Storyboard>
              </VisualState>
              <VisualState Name="Pressed" />
              <VisualState Name="Disabled" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
            <VisualStateGroup Name="FocusStates">
              <VisualState Name="Unfocused" />
              <VisualState Name="Focused" />
            </VisualStateGroup>
          </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
          <Border 
            Name="Border" 
            Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" 
            BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" 
            BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" 
            Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" 
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
            Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" />
          <ContentPresenter 
            TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" 
            HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" 
            Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" 
            RecognizesAccessKey="True" 
            SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" 
            VerticalAlignment="{TemplateBinding VerticalContentAlignment}" />
        </Grid>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

What happens is that nothing happens, the color of the button remains the same. If I change the ColorAnimation line into the following it changes color:

```
<ColorAnimation 
  Storyboard.TargetName="Border"
  Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).Color"
  To="Cyan" />
```

But I need the *To* color to be set by the MouseOverColor property and not be hard coded, how can I achieve this? I have tried all kinds of bindings but the result is always the same.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** It also works if I use a static resource but it is not what I want. Is there really no way to do what I want? It doesn't make any sense to create a new style for each "mouse over" color I want to be able to use and hard code it.

Comment: Have you tried To="{Binding Path=MouseOverColor,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}}"?

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get no change in color.

Comment: Ok, it was just a guess.  TemplateBinding isn't always sufficient.

Comment: Try the more `dynamic` - `{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=YourColorProperty}` if its your own property you want to bind to. See this post I made here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435385/image-height-templatebinding-does-not-work/15435781#15435781. Let me know

Answer (score 2):

According to a Microsoft author in [this MSDN forum thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/027c364f-5d75-424f-aafd-7fb76b10b676/templatebinding-on-storyboard?forum=wpf), what you are trying to do is not supported by WPF. The animation values must be frozen so they can't be dynamic or bound. I just stumbled over the same restriction. No error is being thrown if you try to do it, it just doesn't set any colour.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if that's the solution for your case...

If `MouseOverColor` is your own custom property - try the other way of getting `Templated Binding` to work.

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=MouseOverColor}
```

I have explained it in some more details here

[Image.Height TemplateBinding does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15435385/image-height-templatebinding-does-not-work/15435781#15435781)